# Search two different strings in two columns

Tags: linux, string, shell, multiple-columns

I'm using the shell i have a file with 3 columns, want i want is to search two different strings in the 2 and 3 column. I think awk would be usefull but i cannot find a way to do that properly.

Input file:

```
0000: 3.302295  22.508675
0001: 2.913368  14.100854
0002: 3.530211  19.428879
0003: 3.239985  16.981230
0004: 3.088717  25.245083
0005: 3.156010  3.785273
```

I want to give two search strings like 3.30 and 22.5 and give as output the first line

> 0000: 3.302295  22.508675

Thanks

Comment: Please provide some sample input and desired output. Otherwise answers will be too abstract, I guess.

Comment: show us 1)the example input (the 3 cols file) 2) the two search strings, 3) expected output, 4) better with your codes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this?

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ ! $# -eq 2 ]; then
    echo "Wrong number of parameters"
    exit 
fi

awk -v str1=$1 -v str2=$2 '
{
    if (match($2, "^" str1) && match($3, "^" str2)) {
            print $0;
    }
}'
```

Example:

```
./search.sh 3.175399 21.913555 < input.txt
```

I am assuming that the above script is named search.sh and your input is stoted in input.txt.

**Updated:** added regex anchor as suggested by  glenn jackman

Comment: This one is really the thing i wanted!
Thank you :-)

Comment: Have to be careful: if you want to match at the *beginning* of the word, you need a regex anchor: `awk -v str1="$1" -v str2="$2" 'match ($2, "^" str1) && match($3, "^" str2)'`

Comment: Thanks! and if a want a range of values?
Like from 4 to 6 for the first string and from 2 to 4 for the second string?

Comment: Your script would have 4 parameters.
Thus the line `if [ ! $# -eq 2 ]; then` would be `if [ ! $# -eq 4 ]; then`.
Then the awk command would be `awk -v a=$1 -v b=$2 -v c=$3 -v d=$4 '$2 >= a && $2 <= b && $3 >= c && $3 <= d'`.
To run the script you should type: `./search.sh 4 6 2 4 < input.txt`. Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks!I quite understand the fact about the 4 parameters but not how to express the output, i mean i could use also 4 match functions but in that case there wouldn't be a range of values (from to) but just the perfect matches right?
Probably i misunderstood something, but this are my first tries with awk, so be patient.

Comment: I am not 100% sure I got your doubt. Hope the following helps. The awk with 4 parameters above is the short form of the following: `awk -v a=$1 -v b=$2 -v c=$3 -v d=$4 '{if ($2 >= a && $2 <= b && $3 >= c && $3 <= d) {print $0}}'`. If in awk you specify just a boolean condition it will automatically will print the lines that match that condition. Please note the absence of the brackets in the short form.

Comment: Many thanks. I didn't know about the boolean condition that automatically will print the lines, i will keep in mind for sure.
Now i think is really like i want.
Best regards.

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you:

```
awk -F, '{ if ( $2 == "\"3.30\"" && $3 == "\"22.5\"" ) print $0 }' <filename>
```

I hope it helps! :)

Answer (score 0):

A simple grep looks like it might do the trick:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo -n "First number : "
read n1
echo -n "Second number : "
read n2

# Match lines containing first number, any number of characters, and second number.
grep "$n1.*$n2"  your_file
```

**BUT** this code is a little too simplistic. Maybe you want to input whole numbers like 3 and 1... in which case every line containing a 3 followed by a 1 somewhere would match. With that in mind, here's a solution:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo -n "First number : "
read n1
echo -n "Second number : "
read n2

# Adding decimal separators in case of whole numbers
if [[ $n1 != *.* ]]
then
    n1=${n1}\\.
fi

if [[ $n2 != *.* ]]
then
    n2=${n2}\\.
fi

# Match lines containing first number, any number of characters, and second number.
grep "$n1.*$n2"  your_file
```